# Download from 3rd party repository and upload directly to S3 chunk by chunk

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-upload, download, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service where I want to have a logic to download from a link from some 3rd party storage containing large files and I want to upload to S3. I want to download from the link in chunks and upload in chunks so that I don't go out memory. What are some ways to do this in Java? I tried looking into bunch of docs but I don't see a clear way do it.

I want to download a chunk in local and upload that chunk to S3 and then delete it. I want to do this in a loop until I complete downloading it all.

Any docs or examples that maybe useful for my scenario?

Comment: Is the 3rd-party service an HTTP server, or if not, what protocol does it use?

Comment: It uses http protocol @TimMoore

Comment: is there a specific HTTP library you are using, or are you looking for more general advice?